# luxrender gpu render farm

Tags: rendering, performance

Is it possible to set up a gpu rendering farm? I have a cpu render farm but I would like to make a faster gpu render farm. The gpus I have are a geforce 8400m and a geforce gt 730 my is is ubuntu 14.04. And My internet is definitely fast enough to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set it up via the network renderer addon. But if that's no option for you you could try different things.

### if you use windows

You can control Blender via the command-shell. That means that you can do it with a short batch file as well. You will need 3 batch files for that:

#### setup-client

this file is optional but it makes things a lot easier. It asks for the parameters like start frame, end frame etc. .write it on the master-computer.

#### manager

the manager is a short program that distributes single frames to the seperate render clients and uploads the file together with the parameters to an ftp-server (or a public drive). this program normally runs on the master computer as well.

#### render client

This program starts blender with the parameters submitted by the manager in the GPU rendering mode. An advanced feature would be to make it restart outomaticly if Blender crashes during rendering.

### if you use Mac, Linux or Windows

Create an custom addon for Blender that replaces the batch files.

Comment: Wouldn't shell scripting work just as well as batch files for Mac/Linux?